# Laptop's USB-C port failure

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure, usb-c

Recently my HP laptop's USB-C port failed. This port was not used for charging, but I did use it to connect to a multi-purpose adapter that included an HDMI port, which I used to connect to my monitor. I ran the UEFI hardware check and found that the port is indeed faulty.

I was informed at the HP Community website that this is unfortunately not a replaceable component as it's part of the motherboard. I can live without the port, but I wonder if this is a sign of some potential major failure with my laptop's motherboard. Is there any way of assessing the situation? Are such failures of USB and USB-C ports common in laptops or should I be looking for a replacement as soon as possible?

Comment: Nobody knows. Just continue to use the laptop, as long as it lasts.

Comment: I understand I won't get a specific number, but I am just trying to assess how critical is this situation. For instance, do USB ports fail often in laptops? This was a first for me. Do such failures normally correlate to other major failures? I was just hoping to bump into someone here who perhaps has experience with this.

Comment: The only lame answer possible: If the laptop continues to degenerate, the situation is serious. If it's only one component, it's not serious. Mind your backups, just in case.

Comment: @harrymc thank you, I appreciate your comments. I'm backing up daily so losing data is not my main concern. I just did not expect to potentially be in the market for a new laptop so shortly after buying this one... (only 3 years of use)